# Handling JsonResponse in clientSide view technology of SpringMVC

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement the below scenario in Spring MVC.But I am facing issues and not able to decide about the right Approach.
I am Using jsonRequest/jsonResone(Restful Webservices)

**1.I have a SignUP.jsp Form which contains few field which need to be submitted to controller.**

```
 <form method="POST" onsubmit="javascript:signupObj.signup()">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username : </td>
<td><input  id="username"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password :</td>
<td><input id="password"/></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>



</form>
```

**2.onSubmit of form it will invoke signup javascript function mentioned below**

```
var signupObj  = {
showSignup : function() {
    //There are Two Ways to Declare Function The Other Way is function showSignup().Checkout the reasons
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "showSignup",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#signupView").html( response );
            }
        });
},
 signup : function() {   
     alert("In Signup function");
     var input = '{';
        input += '"username":"'+$('#username').val()+'",';
        input += '"password":"'+$('#password').val()+'"';
        input += '}';
        alert(input);

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "signup",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: input,
         dataFilter: function (response) {
                return response;
            }, 
        // crossDomain: true,
         async:false,
             success: (function(data) {
                 alert("In ajax Sucess");
                 alert(data.profileID);
                 signupObj.redirectview("success",data);
             }),
                error : function(data,textStatus,error){
                    alert("In ajax Failure");
                     alert(error);
                     signupObj.redirectview("failure",data);
                },
             dataType: "json"
     });
     alert("ajax finished");
 },
 redirectview : function(message,data) {
     alert("inside redirect view");
     if(message == "success"){
         url = "success";
     }
     else{
            url = "error";
         }
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url : "success",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: data,
          async:false,
          dataType: "json",
         dataFilter: function (response) {
            return response;
        }, 
         // crossDomain: true,
          success: (function(data) {
              alert("data");

          }),
            error : function(data,textStatus,error){
                alert("In ajax Failure redirect");
                 alert(error);
            },
```

});
     }

};

**3.The Above javascript function does the ajax call to the controller(input is jsonRequest)**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/signup",method=RequestMethod.POST)
      @ResponseBody
        public ProfileDTO signup(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) {
          ProfileDTO profileDto = new ProfileDTO();
//In case no errors in backend logic
          profileDto.setError(null);
          profileDto.setProfileID("profileID");
          profileDto.setProfileName("profileName");
          System.out.println("Submitting SignUP Form Will Return ProfileID");
            return profileDto;

        }
//Below method is for success view
    @RequestMapping(value="/success",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String checkSignup(@RequestBody ProfileDTO profileDto,HttpServletRequest httprequest,HttpServletResponse httpResponse
            ) {
        //model.addAttribute(loginDTO);
    System.out.println("In loginSuccess");
        return "loginSucess";
    }
```

4.The Controller gives the JSON Response of profileDTO. Now based on the profileDTO.getErrors I have to call either loginSuccess.jsp or loginFailure.jsp

**Now My Question is:**

**1) How I can use jsonResponse in ajax call to redirect to loginSuccess.jsp or loginFailure.jsp and how will pass my profileDTO data to the loginSuccess view.**

**2.)Please Suggest me the Best Practice Which should be Followed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) First of all you can `reduce your code` in javascript like below, Directly `serialize` the form object.

```
var signupObj  = {

 signup : function() {   
     alert("In Signup function");
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "signup",
         data: $('#myForm').serialize(),// add "myForm" as the form id 
         async:false,
             success: (function(data) {
                 alert("data"+data);
                 redirectView("success",data);

             })
             error : function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(error_occured);
                    redirectView("error",data);
                }
     });
 }

 };


 <script
 function redirectView(message,data){

 var url = "";
 if(message == "success"){
    url = "/success";
 }else{
    url = "/error";
 }

     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : url,
                    data: data 
                    async:false,
                    success: (function(data) {
                        alert("data"+data);

                    })
                    error : function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(error_occured);
                    }
     });
 }
 </script>
```

2.) Redirect the `success` or `failure` view from the controller itself.

3.) Pass my profileDTO data to the `loginSuccess` view.

Spring MVC, from version 3, allows you to return objects directly converted into JSON using the @ResponseBody annotation in a Controller as shown here

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/signup",method=RequestMethod.POST)
          @ResponseBody
            public ProfileDTO signup(@ModelAttribute("LoginDTO") LoginDTO loginDTO,BindingResult bindingResult) {
              ProfileDTO profileDto = new ProfileDTO();
    //In case no errors in backend logic
              profileDto.setError(null);
              profileDto.setProfileID("profileID");
              profileDto.setProfileName("profileName");
              System.out.println("Submitting SignUP Form Will Return ProfileID");

             return profileDto;


            }
```

**If Forward from controller**

With a `prefix of forward,` Spring will get a `RequestDispatcher` for the specified path and forward to it. Part of that process will include taking the Model from the `ModelAndView` created for that request handling cycle and putting all its attributes into the `HttpServletRequest` attributes.

The Servlet container will take the `RequestDispatcher#forward(..)` and again use your `DispatcherServlet` to handle it. Your `DispatcherServlet` will create a new `ModelAndView` with a new Model for this handling cycle. Therefore this Model doesn't contain any of the attributes from before but the `HttpServletRequest` attributes do.

In your case, this

```
modelMap.put("key", "value");
```

will end up being in

```
HttpServletRequest request = ...;
request.getAttribute("key");
```

Comment: for second ajax call (i.e redirectview)its coming inside the error function. and for the first ajax call(i.e signup) is going inside the success.

Comment: Now the problem is in second ajax call Its not able to invoke the /success of controller.

Comment: @user3745727 mean to say `url : "success",` is being called,but it does not reach your controller.

Comment: yes in success ajax call its goig to the error function

Comment: did you saw the url, is it fine or some problem with the url, Bad Request comes either the url is not mapped or some problem while sending data itself.

Comment: when i do the alert on url is coming a success.

Comment: I have checked in firbud you are correct the data in second ajax call is not going in json format .The format is profileID=Hey+Rahul&profileName=profileName .but in response of first ajax call is in json.I dont know why the format is getting changed whie passing data .Its Strange behaviour.

Comment: {"profileID":"Hey Rahul","profileName":"profileName"} (seen in firebug).This is the JSON Response from the first Ajax call and When I am doing alert on data in second ajax call its giving Object : Object and when seen in firbug the request data is profileID=Hey+Rahul&profileName=profileName .So how can i convert this data back to jSON?

Comment: Thanks for the Help you have provided till now.Appreciate your help I cant voteup as i dont have enough reputation.

Comment: Its giving this error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data when using JSON.stringify.

Comment: @user3745727 give me some time, will look into this

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60021/discussion-on-answer-by-ankur-singhal-handling-jsonresponse-in-clientside-view-t).

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks for chat option